# Getting the classes of HTML input tags when form submitted using ColdFusion

Tags: html, forms, coldfusion

Let me start off with stating that what I'm trying to do might not be the best way to achieve my goal so any suggestions on a better way to do it would be appreciated as well!

### **My Overall Goal:**

Using ColdFusion, validate (and sanitize, if needed) user input when a form is submitted. I'm planning on using jQuery to do the same so that the user can see if there's any issues with their input before submitting but I'm hesitant to rely solely on jQuery as the user might have JavaScript disabled.

**My Current Strategy:** When a user submits a form, have ColdFusion loop through all the inputs and grab each input's "class" attribute. Depending on its class (e.g., "text", "int", etc.) have the user's input validated accordingly.

**My Question:** Is there an "easy" way of grabbing HTML attributes using ColdFusion?

**Notes:**

- I'm running ColdFusion 9
- While doing some searching, I've read several people talking about jTidy and jsoup but they seem like that might be overkill for what I'm trying to do?

Again, I'm all ears for any alternate methods that will achieve what I'm trying to do as well!

Comment: Step 1.  Submit a very simple form with only one input.  On the page that receives the form, and see what variables are avaiable.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that I already have a way of getting all the inputs in the form (using "StructKeyList()").

Comment: Did you see any variables that told you the class of the html input?

Comment: HTML form posts/gets, etc... don't send class attributes when posted.  Do to the fact that your trying to grab this because of the assumpt that javascript will be turned off, your going to have to write a coldfusion page, that performs all of your validation again using cfif's, or case statements.  If it passes then you can finish processing your page, if not, you can include your form back and display the appropriate errors.

Comment: **Dan:** No, all I get is a list of the inputs' names. Which I expected. I was just hoping there'd somehow be a way to "lookup" the associated attributes of the inputs.

Comment: **Steve:** That's what I was afraid of. Could you elaborate on what you're suggesting a bit? I just want to make sure I'm following what you're suggesting.

Comment: You will not be able to get attributes from inputs from CF. You will have to mix a bit of Javascript and CF to do what you want.  Another thing to look at possibly is something like [ValidateThis](http://www.validatethis.org/). I have used this in the past.

Comment: Steve, abbottmw and the answer below give you some solid things to look at... but in its simplest form, your action page could have something simple like cfif isnumeric(form.value) or cfif len(trim(form.value)) gt 5... stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for Cold Fusion to directly* get an input's class.

Indirect methods (these have nothing to do with Cold Fusion, just loading the form with more data to submit)
You could use a hidden field and do things like "fname=string,age=int,lname=string" or separate hidden fields like name="data_fname" value="string".

(Of course, you could use javascript/jquery to build such a hidden form variable, or set of variables, but that negates the whole point of a second, trusted, line of defense.

But all that is silly, because if you're going to do that, it's more reasonable just to do some cfsets on the processing page if this is how you want to setup your validation. Less data being submitted, and 0 chance of interference on the values of these variables.

```
<cfset dtypes = StructNew()>
<cfset dtypes["fname"] = "string">
<cfset dtypes["lname"] = "string">
<cfset dtypes["age"] = "int">
```

And then, if you name your form variables identically, that's easy matching, if you want to do it that way.

```
<cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="fn">
  <cfif StructKeyExists(dtypes,fn)>
    Data type for this form field found, do some matching.
  <cfelseif listfind("field,names,you,don't,want,to,validate,in,comma,delimited,list",fn)>
    Found a field that doesn't need to be validated, like the submit button.
  <cfelse>
    Field #fn# is not exempt from validation, but no datatype was found.
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Or you can just say..

```
<cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="fn">
  <cfif StructKeyExists(dtypes,fn)>
    Data type for this form field found, do some matching.
  <cfelse>
    Field #fn# has no datatype listed, so no validation is performed.
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

You can take this a step further and say

```
<cfoutput><cfset dtypes = StructNew()>
<cfset dtypes["fname"] = "string">
<cfset dtypes["lname"] = "string">
<cfset dtypes["age"] = "int">

<cfset ErrStruct = StructNew()>
<cfset ErrCount = 0>

<cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="fn">
  <cfif StructKeyExists(dtypes,fn)>
    <cfif dtypes[fn] is "string">
      <cfif if_string_validation_fails>
        <cfset ErrStruct[fn] = "#fn# has a bad value.">
        <cfset ErrCount = ErrCount + 1>
      </cfif>
    <cfelseif dtypes[fn] is "int">
      <cfif if_int_validation_fails>
        <cfset ErrStruct[fn] = "#fn# has a bad value for an int.">
        <cfset ErrCount = ErrCount + 1>
      </cfif>
    </cfif>
  <cfelseif listfind("field,names,you,don't,want,to,validate,in,comma,delimited,list",fn)>
    Found a field that doesn't need to be validated, like the submit button.
  <cfelse>
    Field #fn# is not exempt from validation, but no datatype was found.
  </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfif ErrCount gt 0>
  <cfloop list="#StructKeyList(ErrStruct)#" index="en">
    Field "#en#" failed: #ErrStruct[en]#.
  </cfloop>
<cfelse>
  Can input form submission stuff here.
</cfif></cfoutput>
```

The `if_string_validation_fails` and `if_int_validation_fails` are completely made up and mean nothing, here's where you might put your validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

I think worrying about the small percentage of users on a browser with JS disabled is likely least of concern, but of course without knowing the purpose of the site, I will not make that assumption. Here's an article to read to determine if that's something you really need to be concerned about: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/should-i-worry-about-people-disabling-javascript

Once you determine if it's something you really need to worry about, you can move forward and rely on jQuery, optionally using some method for graceful degradation (require them to enable JS for your feature for example).

```
<cfif listLen(structKeyList(form)) GT 0>
    <cfset stcMetadata = deserializeJSON(form._metadata) />
    <cfdump var="#stcMetadata#" />
</cfif>

<html>
<body>
    <form id="myform" method="post">
        name: <input name="name" type="text" class="string" /><br />
        options: 
            <select name="options" class="int">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select><br />
        big text: <textarea name="bigtext" class="string"></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("#myform").submit(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            fields, metadata = {};

        // Get all the form fields
        fields = $this.find(":input");

        // Loop the fields and compile metadata
        fields.each(function () {
            if (this.type !== "submit") {
                metadata[this.name] = $(this).attr("class") || "";
            }
        });

        // Append the field to your form
        $this.append(
            $("<input type='hidden' name='_metadata' />").val(JSON.stringify(metadata))
        );
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Your result:

```
struct

bigtext: string
name: string
options: int
```